# Вопрос по оператору is в C#

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

Что возвращает функция `foo<T>` и зависит ли её результат от `T` (например, если в качестве `T` используется `Nullable<int>`)?

```csharp
static T foo<T>(T a, T c) => (a is T b) ? b : c;
```

Comment: А запустить этот код пробовали? Он работает как вы ожидаете или нет?

Comment: В данном коде проверка вообще бессмысленна, ибо у вас передается тип (`T`), а значит все `T` внутри этого метода будут иметь **указанный тип**. Ну а вы берете и проверяете `если int является int` (если будет `foo<int>` вызван), как-то странно, нет?

Comment: @aepot, да конечно, я ожидал что всегда будет возвращаться **a** а оно не работает как я ожидал - вот и спрашиваю,

Comment: И что [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xxDv1b) не так? Возвращает `a`, как и ожидалось.

Comment: А тип у `null` какой? Я вам ведь говорил, что `null` не является типом. Если нужно, чтоб в случае с `null` выдавало `a`, то так и пишите `a is null`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, если передать `(new Nullable<int>(), new Nullable<int>(10))` то вернёт значение у которого `.HasValue == true` а не `== false` как у `a`.

Comment: Да, вернет как и в первом случае `10` (`c`), ибо `null` это **не тип**, `null` не является `int32` типом. `Nullable<...>` - это обертка над конкретным типом, который допускает значения `null` там, где это невозможно, это не новый тип, а лишь обертка, которая вернет либо указанный тип, либо `null`, не более. Для понимания, напишите `var nullable = new Nullable<int>(10);`, а затем проверьте его тип (`var type = nullable.GetType();`), вам выдаст `int32`, а не `Nullable`. Затем возьмите и удалите `10` (чтоб `HasValue` было `false`, ваш код упадет, ибо в `nullable` у вас будет `null`.

Comment: Что касается `int?` - это так называемый "Синтаксический сахар" для `Nullable<int>`, который позволяет легко и быстро использовать `Nullable`. Другими словами `int?` и `Nullable<int>` - это одно и тоже (можете увидеть [тут](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLuQb2XWPQEsA7AFwH50A1AQwBsBXAUwG4iSA5FppgwBGTNgB4KlAHz1m7GFyQBfIA=) то, во что компилятор преобразует код). Так что, еще раз, `NULL` это не тип, и тем более не `int32` с которым вы сравниваете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, как это "`Nullable<...>` - ... это не новый тип"? Я считаю что это самый настоящий тип, только язык с ним особенным образом работает. Ну а если написать `typeof(Nullable<...>)` то как быть?   
И `null` я теперь вообще нигде и не упоминаю, это вы всё мне про `null` говорите.

Comment: Вот скажите пожалуйста, что не понятного в том, что `Nullable` это обертка над конкретным типом, которая просто позволяет задать дополнительно еще `null`? Что не понятного в том, что при написании `int?` у вас на выходе будет `Int32` тип **или** `null`, но ни как не `Nullable<int>`? Что не понятного в том, что `null != int`? Я вроде все объяснил, но вы продолжаете писать однотипные комментарии, еще и сам вопрос отредактировали в непонятно что. Вот что не понятного в том, что `(a is T b) ? b : c` - если `a` будет `NULL` (что НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ `T`), то условие выдаст `false` и вернет `c`?

Comment: Думаю [отличная демонстрация](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpHqHFRwBs6AKugGYD2DAPNQHwAUtAhgDQ3oAxgEp0AXjboO3dAEsAzgIBGogPzol6EEIDcpIvswYoAFnQBZDqMMEkxe+gBu3AE7oXAU3kBXADYAXcXomDgA7DwB3dAA5P19uJV8PZllQ/05hfnCo2N94xOTU9I44AAZhYT07BwNqmvIATg5PHwDKwwBfZA6gA) того, что я сказал. Внимание на то, во что превращается `a is T`, как видите, там нету сравнений типов, а есть проверка на NULL. Также посмотрите на то, во что превращается `Nullable<int>()`, там передается сразу конкретное значение, которое кастуется в `Nullable` для поддержки `NULL`, но сам тип остается `int`.

Comment: А теперь, смотря на все это, подумайте, `Nullable` является полноценным типом или нет. С точки зрения "классов и структур", может быть и да. А вот с точки зрения объектов и их взаимодействия... Яб не назвал его полноценным типом. Но ладно, пусть будет "еще один тип"...)